# Google Custom Search does not return structured data which I entered using PageMap

Tags: google-maps, search

here is the page map that I added as a comment in the HEAD section

```
<!--<PageMap> 

                        <DataObject type="document">

                        <Attribute name="id">2067</Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="title">Empowering the Middle and Creating Workforce Readiness</Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="urlTitle">Empowering-the-Middle-and-Creating-Workforce-Readiness</Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="category">Business</Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="briefDescription">Join Stacey Harris and Stacia Garr as they share recent Bersin & Associates’ findings regarding the impact of…</Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="description">Have you given enough thought to how you are empowering the middle of your organization? The market has been focused on leveraging top talent, investing in high potentials and preparing executives. But in the midst of all this segmentation, have you thought about the engine of your workforce — your middle management and consistent performers? Over the past several years, companies have asked their employees to do more with less, increase innovation, collaborate and work globally. However, many have failed to give the middle of the organization the support it needs to succeed in today’s modern work environment. <br /><br />Join Stacey Harris and Stacia Garr as they share recent Bersin &amp; Associates’ findings regarding the impact of increasing the capabilities of line managers and the value of motivating and empowering middle performers. The discussion will include examples of how leading organizations are developing leaders from the bottom up, providing tools to help middle performers do their jobs more effectively and improving enterprise career management strategies. Specific case studies will be included in the presentation.<br /><br /></Attribute>

                        <Attribute name="startTime">2011-02-22 11:00:00</Attribute><Attribute name="presenter1">Stacey Harris</Attribute><Attribute name="presenter2">Stacia Garr</Attribute><Attribute name="host1">TM</Attribute>

            </DataObject>

        </PageMap>

        -->
```

When I use the rich snippets testing tool......i get the following error : **"Insufficient data to generate the preview."**

Could anyone help me understand why it is not returning this info as part of the response XML

Answer (score 0):

One of the attributes had HTML elements in it....which causes the XML parsing to fail